# How to print out memory usage by applications?

Tags: 14.04, memory-usage

There are couple of commands to show memory status such as `free`, `top`, `htop`, etc. I want to know how much memory has occupied by my application. Actually, sometimes my Ubuntu is very slow even after restart and although I have 12GB RAM, it's not not normal that slowness. So, I'm looking for a way to show me usage of running apps.

Is there any command for this purpose? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`free`, `top`, `htop` all do what you ask for: they can show the memory used by the applications.

`free` is aggregated, while you can order `top` to show it by usage (with <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> you can choose the sorting column)

Comment: Thanks @dadexix86, but seems < and > just moves the table left and right, isn't there any parameter that I send by `top` to sort it based on usage? thanks

Comment: They do not move the table, they change the sorting order. the default is by CPU, if you go with <kbd>></kbd> it should (on my machine it does) sort it by Memory usage. An alternative is to press M (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>) when `top` is running.

Comment: Awesome, for some reasons < and > doesn't work for me but the shortcut was awesome. Thanks again ;)

Comment: This is weird that they do not work... It is also written in the `man top` "`4c. Task-Area-Commands
[...]               Sorting:     <, >, f, F, R`"

Answer (score 0):

smemstat is another option, it will report memory usage with shared memory divided proportionally between processes

Answer (score 0):

`ps` command will do what you ask for. It prints by default a whole lot of information, but with `-o` flag you can specify the formatting you may want. For instance `ps -e -o "%c %p %v"` will print command, its pid, and it's total memory usage (RAM and swap) in kb.